# Using ajax with Sinatra to update the table

Tags: ruby, ajax, sinatra, rack

I do know how to use ajax with Sinatra for trivial operations such updating a simple text box or something like that: I simply have to send an ajax request and replace the content I want to on `success` event. It's clear for me.

But what should I do when I have a table I want to update using ajax? It's going to be quite difficult to "draw" a table again on `ajax#success`. There certainly should be easier way to achieve that.

Does it exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most efficient way, but you may return the completed HTML-partial for your table to the Ajax-Request, and update the Div-Container on the Page with the table with the result you got back. In most cases this is the easiest way: just swap the content of the div.

Sample Code

action in your sinatra main file:

```
# some code
post "/path/to/your/action" do
  # get the parameters you need and do the update operation, then:
  @goods = Good.all # if you use activerecord, or use what you want to get the list
  slim :goods_table # or haml or erb or ...
end
# some code
```

your view file (i'll use slim here for example):

```
table
  tr
    th title
    th price
    th weight
    th discount
  - @goods.each do |good|
    th
      td = good.title
      td = good.price
      td = good.weight
      td = good.discount
```

I assume your table is placed in a div with the id "goods-table". So the JS with jquery would be something like:

```
$.post("path/to/your/action", {parameter1: x, paramater2: y}, function (data) {
  $("#goods-table").html(data);
});
```

Comment: I think I have to render table by calling  "partial(table_content_partial") from ajax#success. How can I do it?

Comment: do you use jQuery or painful plain javascript?

Comment: I could use anything, it doesn't matter. So do I return "completed HTML-partial for your table" from a Sinatra method?

Comment: give me a minimum sample of the data you want to visualize, eg the model name and some basic attribute-names to render, and i'll write a small sample for you.

Comment: It's the **list** of goods. Good has title, price, weight, discount.

Comment: :goods_table  => the corresponding view in the views-folder of the ap should have the name goods_table.slim.... "#goods-table"  => div with the id "goods-table" on your webpage, which includes the table we're talking about.